# Should I continue with daisy chaining?

Tags: power, mains

I've been daisy chaining power strips and it was no issue until my friend told me it's dangerous. I was using 2 monitors, fan, desktop,55inch TV, monitor speakers, and a phone charger.

And he told me it could be more dangerous in the future as I will add more stereo speakers and amplifier.

However, my dad on the other hand said it is a no issue at all as all my appliances are not demanding in power. Who should I listen to?

Comment: "Questions on the use of electronic devices are off-topic as this site is intended specifically for questions on electronics design." That said, it very much depends on the quality/capability of the power strips and the devices plugged in. A 55in TV + fan + two monitors + amplifier might draw quite a bit of current.

Comment: Not sure why it would be "dangerous" even if they do draw quite a bit of current. It's only dangerous if you use bad extension cords, and they will be dangerous even if you only use one.

Answer (score 2):

The danger is that you could plug in enough devices to overload the wall socket. Your dad is probably right, but to make sure you should add up the Watt or VA ratings of each device you have. If the total is less than the rating of the wall socket (and power strips) then you should be OK.

Some devices may be rated in VA or Watts, while others may only specify Amps. To convert from one to the other use the formula Watts = Volts x Amps, and its inverse Amps = Watts / Volts. Volts is the voltage of your mains (eg. 115V or 230V).

If you have some higher power devices and others that are lower power, try to plug the higher power devices into the strip closest to the wall socket. This will reduce voltage drop through the power strips. Some power strips are not very well made and may have loose sockets which get hot at high current. Obviously the fewer plugs and sockets the current has to go through, the less likely this is to be a problem.

Comment: I had a fused power strip which I blew a couple of times when using a space heater - but only if I powered up my stereo. There were a PC, two monitors (one CRT), stereo, phone charger and the heater plugged in.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the total load is not too much for the outlet in the first place, it would be much better to use a "star" arrangement rather than a "daisy chain" arrangement.

By "star", I mean this: Plug one of the outlet strips into the wall. Then, plug all of the other strips into that first strip. Then plug all of your appliances into those other strips. If there are any outlets left over on the first strip, use them for your heaviest loads.

Only the first strip needs to handle the full power of all the loads together. And each appliance draws power through exactly two or three plug connections, rather than possibly many more with the daisy-chain arrangement.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer by Bruce Abbott, there's an additional danger if you daisychain too many leads, particularly long ones.

If an appliance at the end of the chain shorts out, then the resistance of all the plugs, sockets and wires may mean that the fuse or breaker protecting the whole lot takes too long to trip.  By that time, something might have caught fire.  If the circuit isn't protected by a GFCI/RCD, then the delay could also lead to you being electrocuted.

Comment: I very much doubt that any sensibly sized fuse/breaker for an AC outlet can ever be relied on to prevent death by electrocution under ANY circumstances.